# Is "a constellation of" similar to "a series of"?

Tags: word-choice

> What is artificial intelligence?
> Artificial intelligence is a constellation of many different technologies working together to enable machines to sense,
> comprehend, act, and learn with human-like levels of intelligence. Maybe that’s why it seems everyone’s definition of
> artificial intelligence is different: AI isn’t just one thing.

The above is a sample sentence. I want to know if I can use "a series of" instead of "a constellation of".

Comment: "a series of" suggests some kind of order, while a google search shows constellation to have the meaning of "a group of associated or similar people or things". So no, you cannot use "a series of" unless you want to change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: A *series* suggests a serial process, but the use case here is more of a *network*.

Comment: As technologies are working together (without specific order), you may use **combination** or **mix**. You may also think of **ecosystem**.

Comment: @Graffito an AI with its supporting technologies is definitely not an [ecosystem](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/ecosystem/).

Comment: @Weather Vane : *ecosystem* also means "any complicated system consisting of many different people, processes, activities, etc., especially relating to technology, and the way that they affect each other".

Comment: @Graffito [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecosystem) states that in this context it only *resembles* an ecosystem. [Ecology](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecology) is the study of *organisms* and their environment. An AI is an inanimate machine.

Comment: @Weather Vane : If you google "tech ecosystem", you will see that "ecosystem" is vastly used outside its original biological/environmental domain.

Comment: @Graffito that is a "*technology* ecosystem", not an ecosystem.

Comment: You don't need to use a modifier like "technology" if the context is obvious. And in the above context it's obvious.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since AI is technology, AI ecosystem is a kind of technology ecosystem. In any case, metaphors don't have to map exactly.

Comment: @Barmar the comment to which I originally responded just said AI is an ecosystem. It isn't, but you've brought 'metaphor' to the table, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**What Does It Convey ?**

It is using Imagery or Metaphor or figurative writing technique.

Imagine looking up at the night sky & seeing various Stars. **There is no linear (temporal) Order to the Star Positions.**
Imagine that each Star is a Specific technology.
Imagine that each group of Stars is a group of related technologies.
All the Stars together make up what humans have achieved technologically.

Constellation is a group of Stars.

Hence , we can think about the group of Stars (Constellation) making up the Space Exploration technology , the group of Stars (Constellation) making up the Internet Communication technology , the Constellation making up the Dam technology , the 3D Printing technology Constellation , Medical technology Constellation , Military Weapon Constellation , Etc.

**There is one such Constellation which that writer is wanting to talk about : Artificial Intelligence Constellation.**
It has Stars about Pattern recognition , Logic Processing , Machine Learning , Data Mining , ChatBots , Artificial Neural Networks , Image Processing , Turing Machines , Etc.

I can see that , Primarily , there is only 1 Case of this Usage , though there are lots of Instances of Copy-Paste.
I am not sure who first thought that up , hence I will not give the web-link to that.

**Can you change that to "series" ?**

You can , but then the Imagery will change accordingly. No more Stars & No more groups of Stars.

**Putting the technologies in linear (temporal) Order is a Pre-requisite here.**
You can then use that Imagery or Metaphor or figurative writing technique.

You might have to think about a list of technologies , which may be a technical Dictionary , which may be Standardized by IEEE or other Journals or International technical unions.
**You are then saying that AI is a series of technologies given in that list.**

Example : "Life is a series of accidents." - George Sibley
Here the linear ( temporal ) Order is occurs naturally.